# I want to use curl into curl-php

Tags: php, url, curl

I used below code to fetch all links from given url. It works well but I want to fetch all mailto link and `<h2>` tags for each link. can I use curl into curl? I don't know much about curl. How to do this?

```
<?php   
        $request_url ='http://example.com';

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);    // The url to get links from
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // We want to get the respone
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        $regex='|<a href="(.*?)"|';
        preg_match_all($regex,$result,$parts);
        $links=$parts[1];
        foreach($links as $link){
            echo $link."<br>";
        }

        curl_close($ch);
    ?>
```

Comment: DOMmmmmmmmmmmm with cURL, not cURL into cURL

Comment: i can't understand your question. can you explain more! as i see, you allready have all the links just check them against another regular expression and retrive mailito links!

Comment: it fetches all links but i want all links and for each link i wan to fetch <h2> tags and <a href="mailto:">tags.

Answer (score 0):

you need to parse the returned html (dom) for the links, not another curl request